# MYTYPE of type?

Tags: f#

I have the type declaration

```
type MYVAL = INT of int
```

and want to perform arithmetic operations on constants and variables of type `MYVAL`, like

```
let a : MYVAL = 10
let b : MYVAL = 25
let c = a+b
```

However, when I run it, it claims that `MYVAL` does not support the operator `+`. Isn't `MYVAL` treated as an integer type? If it is not, what does `INT of int` do? How would you perform arithmetic operations of variables and constants of type `MYVAL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MYVAL` is not treated as an integer type. If that's what you want, you can use a type abbreviation; `type MYVAL = int`. I'm not sure why you would want to do that, but it's definitely possible.

In your current definition, `MYVAL` is a single case discriminated union. It wraps a given type, but doesn't inherit any of the underlying type's operators. By the way, the way to construct a an `INT` is `let a = INT 10`, not `let a : MYINT = 10`.

If you want, you can implement your own addition operator, like so

```
type MYVAL = INT of int with
    static member (+) (INT a, INT b) = INT(a+b)
```

which would allow you to do

```
let a = INT 10
let b = INT 25
let c = a+b
```

You would need to do this for any operator you want to use, e.g. `(-)`, `(*)`, etc.

This might all seem a bit confusing, I mean *why* wouldn't we want the operators to be generated automatically? Well, if you're writing a parser, you might want to be able to read either an `int` or a `string`. Such a parser might output a value of a type `type MYVAL = INT of int | STRING of string`. How would `(+)` be defined, then? How about `(-)`?

In the parser example, `MYVAL` would no longer be a *single* case discriminated union, as it has multiple cases. A natural question to ask is, why are single case discriminated unions interesting, then? Who would want to use anything like that? Turns out, it's quite neat for subtyping. Say you want to represent a number that's higher than 10. One way to do this is

```
type HigherThan10 = private Value of int with
    static member TryCreate(x: int) =
        if x >= 10
        then Some(Value(x))
        else None

let x = Value(1) // Error
let y = HigherThan10.TryCreate(1) // None
let z = HigherThan10.TryCreate(10) // Some
```

I know it's not the most interesting example, but it may be used for representing an email adress as a 'subtype' of `string`. Notice, by the way, how this avoids using exceptions for control flow by returning a `HigerThan10 option`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why a simple sum doesn't work was already explained. I'll just show another option: you could define a map2 function for your type:

```
type MYVAL =
    | INT of int
    static member map2 f (INT x) (INT y) = INT (f x y)

//This is the correct way to initialize MYVAL, since it is a single-case discriminated union
let a = INT 10
let b = INT 25

//sum
MYVAL.map2 (+) a b   //INT 35

//mult
MYVAL.map2 (*) a b   //INT 250

//mod
MYVAL.map2 (%) a b   //INT 5
```